# What's the meaning of ladybug when you use for men

Tags: meaning

I would like to ask when you say , he's a ”ladybug”.
Does it have a meaning like "He's a womanizer. or like he's a player."?

Comment: Maybe a reference to the rhyme (where bug and bird are interchangeable) *"Ladybird, ladybird fly away home, Your house in on fire and your children are gone"* ?

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen that usage. My inclination is to think it is idiosyncratic. But, at least one ***[slang dictionary](http://slang.uoregon.edu/pub_search.lasso?RecordIDNumber=19428&Process=detail01)*** defines the word in this context as follows:

> - "a boy who is as insecure about relationships as a "girl" should be."

One of the senses in the ***[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ladybug)***  is similar and akin to metrosexual:

> - "A flamboyant man that is actually straight.
>     *She's dating a ladybug. I could've sworn he was gay.*"